# Worklight - connection on startup fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

using Worklight server v6.1 i'm trying to develop a simple app that connects to the production server at startup. To get this i do:

- in `initOptions.js` file i set `connectOnStartup` to `true`
- in `wlCommonInit` method of `<my-app>.js` file i call :

  `WL.Client.connect({
                  onSuccess: connected,
                  onFailure: failure
              });`

where `connected` and `failure` are two callback to two simple functions that load some data in a listview. When i trie it on a production or development environment i get a spot over my app's layout stating it's loading as you can see in the pic below(even if the application loaded data correctly):

[image]

i notice that after installing and running it on an iOS or Android device i don't have this strange behaviour, but on Windows8 devices i do have.

i set to false connectOnStartup and left only the call to WL.Client.connect. 
Now the app doesn't get blocked anymore(i suppose becouse WL.Client.connect runs asynchronously while WL.Client.init does not but it's only my opinion).

i can't connect to the server yet, this is strange becouse(you can see in the pic) there is a listview filled with data returned by a sql adapter,

so it looks like the app can connect to the server for calling adapters but not for updates

Comment: What do you mean by "updates"?

Comment: by updates i mean hotfixes, using the connectOnStartup option set to true and installing the app in iOS and Android devices i experimented that i can upload hotfixes in the production server and all apps installed in any clients get updated on successive starting.

Comment: i suppose this is the main purpose of calling WL.Client.Connect at the application startup. isn't it?

Comment: What you are referring to is called Direct Update, and this feature is available at this time only for Android and iOS. Also, there are more things that happen on app startup (if set to connectOnStarstup: true, like remote notification or remote disable. Please consult with the documentation. Also, what is the status of this question?

Comment: i'm gonna distribute an app over some customers, if they use Windows8(both v8.0 and v8.1) or Windows Phone 8 can't they update directly the app i distribute? Do they have to manual uninstall/reinstall it from the Windows store?

Comment: Because Direct Update is not available for Windows 8 / Windows Phone 8 yet, the answer is Yes.

Comment: Are there any plans to extend this feature?

Comment: and, also, where can i find the complete list of features not available using MS based devices?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46244/discussion-between-riccardo-and-idan-adar)

Comment: Obviously, I cannot comment on future plans. If you are a customer, you can submit feature requests or talk with your IBM contact. See this table for feature comparison: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already set `connectOnStartup:true` in `initOption.js`, this means that the app will try to connect to the Worklight Server on startup - basically it calls to `connect`, so why do you call `WL.Client.connect` in `wlCommonInit()` as well?

As for the onSuccess and onFailure, I think that in this what you may want is the following:
[See the options for WL.Client.init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html).

There is an initOption that you can uncomment in `initOptions.js`:

- **onConnectionFailure**

> A failure-handling function invoked when connection to the Worklight
>   Server, performed on initialization by default, or if the
>   connectOnStartup flag is true, fails.

The "success" by default is `wlCommonInit()`, but you want something else then in `initOptions.js` you can also add `onSuccess: something`.

---

BTW, where did you see what you've done  as a "best practice" by Worklight?

Comment: please see my edited answer, for best practices i mean comments found when creating an empty hyprid app under the wlCommonInit method. i misunderstood conditions to be applied both and not only one of them.

Comment: @Riccardo, if your question is answered - please mark this answer as "Answered".