# Windows Phone 8 application with jQuery is not properly displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hybrid application with supported environment on iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows.

The application is working perfectly fine on Development Server, but when I move the same application to Production Server, the Windows version stops working (all other platforms are working fine)

The application loads and shows the RSS Feed, however, the jquery panel menus, jquery nivo sliders etc are not loading, the application also fails to resize itself according to the screen size. So I have a feeling that the JQuery elements are being blocked/stopped on Windows Platform somehow.

Visual Studio is showing a lot of exceptions, but I believe none of them is fatal. log available [here](http://pastebin.com/m885sLRd)

Application Code:

```
function wlCommonInit() {

//First Landing Page
currentPage = "Public/News/html/news.html";
currentJs = [ "Public\\News\\js\\news.js","Public\\News\\js\\jquery.nivo.slider.js"];


//Connect WL Server to get User Preference
WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: onConnectSuccess, onFailure: onConnectFailure});

   if ((WL.Client.getEnvironment() == "windowsphone8") || (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == "android")) 

  {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', handleBackButton);
    });
}

eventCall();
$(".logout").hide();

// lock icon - student services
$(".student .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").css({
    'background-image' : 'url(images/lock-red.png)',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
    'background-position' : ''+lockdir+''
 });         

// lock icon - employee services
$(".employee .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").css({
    'background-image' : 'url(images/lock-red.png)',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
    'background-position' : ''+lockdir+''
 });         

// service item hover
 $('#scrollableContent').on('click','li', function() {

        $('#scrollableContent li').css({background: 'transparent'});
        $(this).removeClass('ui-body-inherit');
        $(this).css({background: '#554e46'});
        $(this).removeClass("ui-bar-" + theme);
        $(this).css({background: ''});
        $(this).removeClass('ui-bar-a ui-bar-b ui-bar-c ui-bar-d ui-bar-e');
        $(this).addClass("ui-bar-" + theme);

});

//for menu swiper
swiper();

//for push notification
if (WL.Client.Push) {

    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {
        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback("myPush", "PushAdapter",
                "PushEventSource", pushNotificationReceived);
    };

}
$("#apppage").show();
```

}

I have tried checking the error by switching on the HTTP trace for the value, complete log available [here](http://pastebin.com/Zuthqc0r)

Comment: the funny part is Android application is using same security tests and also waiting for user Interaction , but still Android Application is working fine.

Comment: Not helpful. Describe better what do you mean by "stops working". Is there a crash? What do you see in the Visual Studio output view?

Comment: The application loads and shows the RSS Feed, however, the jquery panel menus, jquery nivo sliders etc are not loading, the application also fails to resize itself according to the screensize. So I have a feeling that the JQuery elements are being blocked/stopped somehow. 

Visual Studio is showing a lot of exceptions, which were shown in past as well.

I have applied application authenticity as well, and application is failing Authenticity checks as well, but if I block the Application from server, the application doesn't start at all (RSSFeed doesn't load).

Comment: Application is not crashing it calls wl.connect and get hanged and do not start the application with main.js file

Comment: Obviously no one can help you with your applicative code if you are not providing code. If you can't share your customer app, work on recreating the issues in a new application. We'll wait.

Comment: The problem only comes when we move from Development (Eclipse) to Production environment. 

The application is able to work and communicate with MobileFirst Development Server and runs smoothly. However, when the same application is deployed on Production server, it stops working. 

Let me know what code, might help you in understanding the problem, and I can post it.

Comment: You wrote that your jQuery Mobile implementation is failing, so what can we do about that w/out looking at it? You're also saying that authenticity is failing, yet your log makes no mention of that. In short, you're mentioning multiple problems in 1 questions. Perhaps you should open a PMR instead.

Comment: Hi Idan, sorry if I confused you, the main problem for which I have this thread created is
"application is calling WL.Connect and Gets Hanged and do not start the application with Main.Js file? 

The other information which I mentioned are just extras that these problems are also happening but not the cause of this issue.

Comment: 1) Remove information that is not related. 2) provide the full files: messages.log, trace.log. Also attempt to inspect the network by using wireshark when authenticity is enabled.

Comment: I do not see <testAppAuthenticity/> defined within this securityTest.
   This is mostly why application authenticity check is failing.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.workl
ight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html

Comment: @VivinK In the above section I removed testAppAuthenticity so that at least the application runs. But even after removing the Authenticity checks, the application fails to run.

Comment: @VivinK I have update the link for logs of Visual Studio and Trace in the post. Please let me know if you think anything is missing.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have added the Code snippet for your review, also I have found an earlier post with similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402243/worklight-connection-on-startup-fails

The only difference which I have is that I am not interested in DirectUpdate but calling WL.Client.connect to download user preferences saved in my server.

Comment: whats the version of the phone OS?

Comment: Hi Ajay, I had two phones one with Windows 8 and other with 8.1 , both didn't work. 

What I figured out the reason was the problem that some procedure calls were getting initiated even before WL.client connect call. 

I changed the order and added some delays, which resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that some delay due to HTTPS encryption/processing allowed some other procedure calls to be made even before WL.Client Connect completed its execution.

What I did as a work around was to delay other calls so as to ensure that WL.Client Connect completes before any other calls are executed.